# silence in front of generated audio mpegts

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

./ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i  a.ts -acodec aac -strict -2 -loglevel debug audio.ts

Input #0, aac, from 'a.ts': 
  Duration: 00:00:05.06, bitrate: 126 kb/s 
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s

if I convert a.ts and audio.ts into .wav 
I will get two wav files, one of them has silence in front of it.  I used audacity to determine that about 0.031s 
audio.ts will have some silence. 
I can see that a.ts has 215 audio frames 
and audio.ts 216.

Any explanations why is silence added to ts? How to turn that off?